# If statement to calculate else copy and paste?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some existing code that looks at multiple columns and copies data from one tab to another, but I need to enter extra code which recalculates one of these columns before it pastes it into the new tab. I've searched far and wide for help but found little which can help.

In summary, I need VBA code which searches a column in Excel, recalculates values in another column based on its findings, then copies and pastes the values range to a new Sheet once done.

To illustrate ...

Sheet 1:

- Column A has a series of dollar values
- Column B has codes, either X or Y

I need code which effectively says:

```
If column B = X  
Then multiply value in Column A* 2  
Else leave as is
```

Then copy Column A into Sheet 2 column C (or any column at this point, really)

I have tried to write the code myself but I'm still a beginner and struggling. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Can you show us your code, and detail what errors you're getting, or where it's going wrong?

Comment: And also add a screenshot of your data

Comment: Actually, do you need VBA? A formula in column C coul be `=IF(B1="X",A1*2,A1)`, then copy down, copy/paste as values to Sheet2 Col. C?

Comment: To clarify, I have code which copies data from one tab of an excel book to another. This code works well. Note, the data is in columns. It is one of these columns which needs to be recalculated before it’s pasted into the new tab, and it’s for this I need code which I’ve struggled to write with any effectiveness.

Comment: Also, I need code instead of a formula since I’m building a model for others to inherit and use. The people inheriting this have limited excel skills

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, i As Long, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Amount As Double

    'Set worksheets
    With ThisWorkbook

        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")

    End With

    'Find Last row of sheet 1 column A
    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Start looping rows from row 1 to lastrow1
    For i = 1 To LastRow1

        'If the value if X or Y
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = "X" Then
            Amount = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value * 2
        Else
            Amount = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        End If

    'Find Last row of sheet 2 column C
    LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy data
    ws2.Range("C" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = Amount

    Next i

End Sub
```